# Proving diagonalization and inreversibility in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, theorem-provers

I'm trying to prove two statements related to matrices but I can't find a good way to prove it:
$$
T:R^{2}\rightarrow R^{2}
$$$$
S:R^{2}\rightarrow R^{2}
$$ Are linear transformations.
What is the best way to prove that, if T and S are nondiagonalizable then (T ◦ S) is nondiagonalizable ?

I'm also trying to prove that, If T and S are non-invertible then (T + S) is non-invertible.

Those two questions are giving me some trouble - I can't find a good way to prove it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:theorem-provers]?

Comment: Where on earth did these come from? Both are trivially false.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example?

Comment: @WoodySilva See my answer to your twin here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316152/how-to-do-the-diagonal-matrix-proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is false, because let $A:= \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and
$B:=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$. A and B have rank 1 so A and B aren't invertible. But $A+B=I_2$ wich is invertible.